# htaccess redirect based on get value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some pages based on a value retrieved in the url.

It is necessary for me do it with `htaccess`.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/products.php?id=1040

http://www.example.com/products.php?id=1041

http://www.example.com/products.php?id=1042
```

If the id value is greater than 1039 and less than 1501, apache must redirect to another page:

```
http://www.example.com/otherpage.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %1 >1039
RewriteCond %1 <1501
RewriteRule ^/?products\.php? /otherpage.html? [L,R=301]
```

The first condition groups the numeric ID making it available as a backreference via **%1**. The next two conditions checks that this numeric ID is greater than 1039, and less than 1501. If all 3 conditions are met, the request for `/products.php` is redirected to `/otherpage.html`. The `?` at the end ensures that the query string *is not appended to the end*.

Answer (score 0):

With this sort of specific requirement, I would think performing the redirect at the application level rather than in Apache would be most appropriate.  Just compare the value fo `$_GET['id']` and redirect via `header()` as appropriate.

Either that or you have to write a relatively complex regex to search for values between 1040 and 1500 within a `RewriteCond` as a regular `RewriteRule` doesn't operate against query strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule condition/ http://www.example.com/otherpage.html [P]
```

However I am not sure how easy it would be to get redirect over param values.